# My TypeScript Button isn't responding to user input

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

```js
function test(event)
{
    document.getElementById('ausgabe').innerHTML =
    'test';
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    document.getElementById("input1").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
        test(event);
    })
})
```

Clicking the Button does basically nothing. The website doesn't change when I'm clicking it.

Comment: Where is the button you're referring to? Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'submit'` is an event of `<form>`, not of `<button>`.

Change your code to this:

```
function test(event)
{
    document.getElementById('ausgabe').textContent = 'test';
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    const button = document.getElementById("input1");
    const form   = button.form;
    form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
        test(event);
    })
})
```